# Using external files like excel instead of OBject repository in QTP/UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft14

Is there any methods or function available where i can use excel as Object Repository instead of Local or Shared repository?

For example : In a given excel i will have the unique name like `"wedit_SignOn"`with its unique property eg `"class:=username","type:=username"`.
So in excel i will save it as `Sheet1.cells(1,1)` will have the unique  name `"wedit_SignOn"` and on `Sheet1.cells(1,2)` will have  the property `"class:=username","type:=username"`

Comment: No. You have to write custom functions to achieve this. What is the issue with OR anyways?

Comment: @PankajJaju... Its funny, but our   "Senior Management" wants  that way as it will be easy  to maintain and modify. :P

Comment: There is no way its going to be easy to maintain such an Excel. If the object properties change, UFT will provide you a quick and easy way to update your OR and tests. Excel, not so much. Convince your management about how the Excel approach is worse than OR rather than wasting your time in creating such a tool.

Answer (score 0):

Not natively, but you can write your own using Descriptive Programming (although I wouldn't recommend it). You need to specify the class and properties of the object, for example:

objectClass: someClass, property1: property1Value.

Then in the code you could something like this:

```
select case objectClass

  case "someClass"

    set testObject = someClass(property1 & ":=" & property1Value)

  case "otherClass"
    ...

end select
```

But you would need to cover every class you need and handle multiple properties as well...overall pretty complicated. I understand that OR is not ideal - for me mostly because it's a binary file so it's hard to version and impossible to maintain outside of UFT.

Comment: You can import/export OR in XML format - so you can play with it outside the UFT but I don't see why you would want to do that.

Comment: I'm storing it in DB for example.